# How to make my Yii2 urlManager Rule works? It returns 404 error

Tags: rest, yii2, rules, pretty-urls, yii2-urlmanager

Please provide me some light!

I have this existing rule

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => UrlRule::class, 
                    'controller' => ['login', 'persons', 'details', 'paytypes', 'jobs', 'job-cost-codes', 'cost-centers', 'js-assets', 'asset-use-codes'],
                    'pluralize' => false,
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                        'GET {id}' => 'view',
                        'PUT {id}' => 'update',
                        'DELETE {id}' => 'delete',
                    ],
                    'tokens' => [
                        '{id}' => '<id:[\w-]+>'
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'Gets all expenses of a given person id',
                    'pattern' => 'persons/<id:\w+>/expenses',
                    'route' => 'details/expenses/',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

The firs rule is working fine, but the second one with the defined name, pattern, and route is not.  It returns 404. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try to change their positions

Comment: The configuration seems to be correct. What is the URL you are testing with?

Comment: What do you get when you set defaults parameter for "id" like so: 'defaults' => ['id' => 1], you can also remove the slash at the end of your route parameter